# Programmatically User login not working in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to login users programmatically in Drupal 8. Here goes my code.

```
if(isset($uid)) {
      $user = User::load($uid);
      user_login_finalize($user);
      $user_destination = \Drupal::destination()->get();
      $response = new RedirectResponse($user_destination);
      $response->send();
      exit(0);
    }
```

I am getting the message 'Session opened for...' in watchdog. But the user is not logged in. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Using exit() in controller is not a good idea. Drupal produces many more actions after executing the controller, but exit() stops the script before they are executed. To avoid this, you must return RedirectResponce() from your controller:

```
if(isset($uid)) {
  $user = User::load($uid);
  user_login_finalize($user);
  $user_destination = \Drupal::destination()->get();
  $response = new RedirectResponse($user_destination);
  return $response
}
```